# cannot create another file after delete another because it is used by another process

Tags: c#, file, process

I know that this is a very common problem, I tried to use processes, but it doesn't work. So, I want an user to be able to upload photos, to create its own avatar. What I do, is to take the selected photo, I resize it , than I crop it and save it in application/bin. If he chooses another photo again,  I delete the first photo and I create another. After I delete the photo, I get this error:

```
The process cannot access the file : 'C:\.." because it is being used by another process.
```

Code:

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

         Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
         dlg.Title = "Open Image";
         dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string fileName = dlg.FileName;
                Uri uri = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage(uri);
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(fileName);
                b = ResizeImage(b, 100, 100);
                b = CropCircleImage(b);

              string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"UserPhotos\";
              string file =Button.Content.ToString()+".bmp";

                if (File.Exists(path + file))
                    File.Delete(path + file);

              //after it gets out from the if statement, I get the error
                  b.Save(path + file);       

                Uri newuri = new Uri(path + file, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

               ((ButtonLogin)sender).Image= new BitmapImage(newuri);
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you're not keeping the file open while running this code. Dispose any Bitmaps that refer to the old file first. Oh, and do _not_ store anything in the application bin folder. Normal users don't have write access to that directory.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Sorry, I don't understand exactly what do you mean by 'de-referencing'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because you are updating the image of a particular user and you are trying to delete the old one and upload the updated one when the old one is in use. Try 'de-referencing' the old one and then upload the new one.

Sorry for the word De-referencing. By it I mean to say is to check whether that image is used somewhere else and is locked. If so, unlock it and upload the new one.

Comment: I don't really understand this. Can you be more specific about what you mean by de-referencing. It's not a term I've ever heard used in this context.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I was not able to frame the exact word at that moment. I explained it to the author of the question what I meant. I am making necessary changes in my answer.

Comment: How does one programmatically go about unlocking the file? Surely the solution is to close the file correctly.

Comment: Trying with the same. I think it is related to file close. +1 
@DavidHeffernan

Comment: I posted here a sample that shows my error. I tried to rename the file, and after that to save it, but it didn't work   https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C4D9AAB68574ED9C%21109

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, either your process, or another process has opened the file and locked it so that your program is not able to open the file. Typically this happens when, due to a coding error, you fail to properly close the file.

The error in your code is probably not in the code that you have shown. Most likely the error is in code that you have not shown. Code that opens the file but then fails to close it.

If you cannot work out which process holds a lock on the file you can use a debugging tool like Process Monitor or Process Explorer. These tools can both show you which process holds the lock on the file.

Comment: I don't open any file. I just create another image from the selected image, which is smaller and cropped, after I save it in my application folder. If a file already exists in the folder with a specific name, I delete it , and after that I create another, with the new selected image. I don't know exactly where to use process. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Tracey: As said, the problem is probably not in the code you've shown. You seem to be using the file somewhere else (namely where the avatar is being used). `Bitmap(string)` is locking the file until the Bitmap is disposed!

Comment: Thank you. I posted the entire code, seriously.It crashes at line: b.save(path+file).  Ok, I will try harder